# how to make stay in the last language when android app is closed?

Tags: java, android, string, android-layout

I have already made an app android to change the language. But when the app is closed and the open again, the language back to the default language.
How can i make when app open again and the language is the last choose by user?

Thanks for help and i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

you need to save the user selected language to shared preference or any other persistent storage, on next app launch retrieve the language previously selected and apply it to the application.

when user changes the language, in order to apply the new laguage activity should be **finished and restarted** or else you need to call **recreate()** method of the activity.

https://github.com/gunhansancar/ChangeLanguageExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/gunhansancar/changelanguageexample/helper/LocaleHelper.java

Copy the above class to your code.

In your activity override the below method.

```
 @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(LocaleHelper.onAttach(base));
    }
```

When user change the language ,e.g its on button click. save the language using below code. Here **en** is the language (iso) code for english.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     LocaleHelper.persist(context,"en");
     recreate();
}
```

Comment: But how to do that? Along with this please add relevant code as well.

Comment: https://github.com/gunhansancar/ChangeLanguageExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/gunhansancar/changelanguageexample/helper/LocaleHelper.java . Try this link.

Comment: this is not the correct way by just sharing link or few sentences. Your answer should be just a comment. Flagged!

Comment: @VicJordan We should not share link ? Am new here . Thanks for the info.

Comment: you can add links from trusted/official sources to your answer BUT relevant code is mandatory if question is related to some code.

Comment: Sharing links is fine, but the answer should be an answer even if the link rots, so it needs enough code in the answer to be understandable. You may include even the scaffolding/boilerplate code in the answer, or leave that for the link, that's a matter of taste, you'll see both often enough.

Answer (score 0):

By default the language of app will be falling back to device locale as a result each time you restart your app the language will change.

In order to make your app's language same as user's choosen preference, you need to persist the language chosen by user. One way is to store the language preference in SharedPreference. When the app is launched, check for the value in preference to decide which Language should be used and then adjust your view accordingly.

You can do it as follows

Store value as follows when language is changed:

> SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MyPref",
>   MODE_PRIVATE).edit();  editor.putString("language", "en"); 
>   editor.commit();

Retrieve value as follows in `onCreate()`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE); 
String selectedLanguage = prefs.getString("language", "<enter default locale of app>");
setLocale(selectedLanguage);
```

**Eventually set the locale as follows:**

Without Activity restart:

Set `android:configChanges="locale"` in your  in manifest

Change your setLocale as follows:

```
private void setLocale(String lang) {
    Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    onConfigurationChanged(conf);//Add this line
}
```

Override onConfigurationChanged():

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    textView.setText(<your-text>);
    //Any other UI text to change
}
```

Alternatively you can call `recreate();` once locale is changed.
This will ensure your locale is changed correctly.

Comment: @VicJordan sure. Done