# How to make android app independent on phone locale?

Tags: java, android

My android app asked user for preferred language first time, my problem is that my app language change automatically at runtime if I change device language while app running in background, and after restart the app, language of app retained as it before irrespect of phone locale, I want to its language not change at all at runtime.

Here is my code of locale-

```
public void setLanguage(Context context, String language) {
        final Locale locale = new Locale(language);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        final Configuration configuration = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
        configuration.locale = locale;
        context.getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Comment: have you checked my answer on this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053724/how-to-make-stay-in-the-last-language-when-android-app-is-closed/51053794#51053794)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make stay in the last language when android app is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51053724/how-to-make-stay-in-the-last-language-when-android-app-is-closed)

Comment: have you tried the solution? The phrasing is bit different but overall its same

Comment: I have not done it yet but yeah I read again your post and it seems quite similar, ok I do it, sorry for my naive question as I am very new to android, and thanks for given link.